# DAX - filtering out whole row from data table that meets certain condition(s)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like following:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Store Name</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Week Number</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Sales</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Sales-LY</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store A</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">1</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">20</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store A</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">2</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">25</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store A</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">3</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">30</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store B</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">1</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">15</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store B</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">2</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">15</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store B</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">3</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">20</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store C</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">1</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">30</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store C</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">2</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">0</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Store C</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">3</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">25</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to return (lets' say) a pivot table with

Salex IDX = SUM(Sales)/SUM(Sales-LY) as a measure, ignoring the data points for "Week 2 for Store C".
So it's not a filter on just Week Number or Store, but its a filter on specific row(s) identified by multiple parameters.

Essentially, i would like to get 'like for like' results, excluding any weeks where Sales or Sales-LY columns are zero(or null)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the solution is something using CALCULATETABLE but couldn't find a solution that works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a calculated column to concatenate Store and Week, something like this:

`=[Store Name]&", Week: "&[Week Number]`

Then you can use a filter or slicer to exclude the Store & Week combination you want.

Comment: Surely this is a way, another way I am currently using is creating a conditional column which results in "1" if Sales or Sales-LY is 0 for a given day. But I am still curious if there is a DAX based solution for this.

Comment: Solution for what?  I think you need to expand on your question.  What are your expected results?

Comment: I thought i made it clear in my initial question. I would like a solution within the calculated measure (without altering the data tables). For example Sales Change, that will exclude the rows when Sales LY or Sales TY row has a zero or null value.

Comment: Ok, thinking through it one more time. I already have my solution, calculated column does not alter the original tables... Thanks. Now I have a follow up question on it, how can I identify the stores with consecutive (back to back) zeroes and then filter out the rows that had at least two consecutive weeks with zero sales? any ideas on this?

Comment: As I understand SO conventions, this should be a separate question.